# SAS Program to call a UNIX Bash Shell script

Tags: sas

Can I call a Bash Shell Script from SAS code? Our scheduler can run only the SAS code. It runs the SAS code on a Linux box. I don't want to run the script on CRONTAB, but want to schedule it through a SAS program. Is there an option for that?

I tried using

```
DATA _NULL_;
CALL SYSTEM('/My_Script.sh')
RUN;
```

But it did not work

Comment: Did you get any error messages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately many SAS servers are configured to disallow executing OS commands (this is the default that SAS ships).  To check this setting on your SAS server, you can submit:

```
%put %sysfunc(getoption(xcmd));
```

If this returns NOXCMD, it means you will need to speak with your SAS admin to plead your case that they should turn on the XCMD option to that you can execute OS commands.

Comment: It returned NOXCMD, after getting it changed to XCMD then %x(".\my_script.sh"); ran fine